# Djangobb - receiving incorrect link for confirmation

Tags: python, django

I set up djangobb and after a lot of problems and hours spending to making it work with my app, it finally worked... The only problem I still have is that when someone register, he is receiving incorrect link for registration.

Example:

```
http://example.com/forum/account/activate/eac687ca1d21c4ae0f33d61766fec3a289936dbf/
```

How can i edit the url to my own url ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it in `/admin/sites/site`. If you want to use different sites for development and production versions, you can make use of `SITE_ID` setting which is decribed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id).

Answer (score 0):

Change it in `/admin/sites/site/`.